# How to set up a project with more than one repository

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a project that is currently partially in source control. It is set up so that when I push the project to git, it is automatically deployed, my current folder structure looks like this:
[image]

The code from AsoRock.Core compiled in to a DLL and copied in to the AsoRock.Web folder - and it is the AsoRock.Web files that are actually pushed in to source control.

I now want to put all the other files and folders in to a separate git repository. So I want all AsoRock.Core folder, the Merchello-2.7.0 folder and the packages folder to be stored in this new repository.

Can anyone give me an step by step of how I can do this? I'm using source tree as a git client, but if I need to use the command line to set it up initially I will try that too.

Ideas please?

Comment: Please replace the picture with text.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to create a repository with submodules - this way they are independent (with its "own repository"), but linked through a parent...

In detail, you could check [this link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Simplifying, to create submodules you should follow this (extracted from the link above):

> Let’s start by adding an existing Git repository as a submodule of the repository that we’re working on. To add a new submodule you use the git submodule add command with the absolute or relative URL of the project you would like to start tracking. In this example, we’ll add a library called “DbConnector”.

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector
```

> By default, submodules will add the subproject into a directory named the same as the repository, in this case “DbConnector”. You can add a different path at the end of the command if you want it to go elsewhere.

In order to clone a project with submodules:

> Here we’ll clone a project with a submodule in it. When you clone such a project, by default you get the directories that contain submodules, but none of the files within them yet:

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/chaconinc/MainProject
```

To update a submodule, you use:

```
$ git submodule update --remote
```

To push changes on a submodule:

```
$ git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
```

I think this would be the basics. The link above has further details if you need more than this.

I hope it helps you...